# Integral of log of incomplete lower gamma function

Tags: calculus, entropy

I'm trying to evaluate the following integral

$\int_{0}^{\infty}\left( 1-\frac{\gamma(a,bx)}{\Gamma(a)}\right) \,  \ln\left( 1-\frac{\gamma(a,bx)}{\Gamma(a)}\right) \, dx$ for $b>0$ and $\gamma(a,bx)$, the lower, incomplete Gamma function.

It seems like a complete mess. I'm guessing this doesn't possess a closed form solution but what kind of special functions can be used to express it ?

Comment: It is also $\int_0^\infty Q(a,bx)\ln(Q(a,bx))dx$ with [gamma regularized](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=gammaregularized)

Comment: ahh. didn't know that. Thanks